# How can I close featherlight gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

I'm seeking the best way to disable looping and close my featherlight gallery when a user attempts to navigate past the last slide.
Here's my code hack so far (navigateTo: in featherlight.gallery.js):

```
    navigateTo: function(index) {
      var self = this,
      source = self.slides(),
      len = source.length,
      $inner = self.$instance.find('.' + self.namespace + '-inner');

      /* begin custom code */
      if (index >= len) { 
        //we are past the last slide, so close
        $.featherlight.close(null);
        return false;
      }
      /* end custom code */

      index = ((index % len) + len) % len; /* pin index to [0, len[ */
      ...
```

I'm a still very much a jQuery and javascript beginner. And I strongly suspect there is a better way to do this. Any suggestions? Many thanks!